# Linking two .so objects with same class names definition (compilation is done)

Tags: c++, linker

Hi I am trying to link two .so library which have same class definition and which are  interacting with each other I order to avoid class name conflict during compilation I am putting them in a separate wrapper.

I am able to compile it properly but my doubt is that is that a fool proof solution? or I can get see some error during simulation due to conflicting class name definitions?

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

If you have classes with identical names, then probably you have poor design. How do you expect your code to tell which is which? If you have to use them both, you're doomed. If this naming makes sense in different contexts, you should put your classes in separate namespaces. C++ will include namespace name when class symbols will be mangled, so with this you won't have any conflict.